# How do I alternate letter colors on a webpage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to alternate the colors of every letter in a specific div on my webpage using javascript.

I found this script on a forum that alternates the color of the words of a div using a form select:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var HTML = '';

    function alternate(colorpair) {
    var el = document.getElementById('alternator');
        if (!HTML) HTML = el.innerHTML;
            colorpair = colorpair.split('|');
            var text = HTML.split(' '), output = '';
            for (var w=0; w<text.length; w++) {
                output += '<span style="color:' + ((w%2) ? colorpair[0] : colorpair[1]);
                output += ';">' + text[w] + '</span> ';
            }
            el.innerHTML = output;
        }
    </script>
```

Here's the html  to go along with it:

```
    <div id="alternator" class="none">
        This is how the line of text should look after the alternating color effect is applied. And so on, and so forth....
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <form>
        <select style="font:200 11px arial;color:white;background:#333333;" onchange="alternate(options[selectedIndex].value)">
            <option>select colors</option>
            <option value="red|yellow">red & yellow</option>
            <option value="coral|olive">coral & olive</option>
            <option value="green|purple">green& purple</option>
            <option value="gold|silver">gold & silver</option>
            <option value="skyblue|darkorange">skyblue & dark orange</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

As I said above, this script uses a **form** to change the color of the **words**.

Can I alter this so that the **letters** alternate **automatically** upon page load?

Comment: Don't split by space, just iterate over the string.

Comment: try calling the function on body's `onload=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem #1: No need to define var HTML outside of the scope of the function. No need to define it at all, really.

Problem #2: You are splitting by a space ' ' which would alternate words, not letters.

Problem #3: You're not stripping out existing tags, so if you select a color pair once, then select another, you'll be putting html into your text.

Problem #4: If you select 'select colors', it will throw an error trying to get colorpair[1] which won't exist

Problem #5: You're adding spaces at the end of each letter, which will break further attempts, as each alternating character will be a space. You'll only see one color! :P

Fixed code:

```
function alternate(colorpair) {
    if(colorpair.indexOf('|') == -1) return;
    var el = document.getElementById('alternator');
    colorpair = colorpair.split('|');
    var letters = el.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,''). /*strip leading/trailing spaces*/
                  replace(/<[^>]*>/g,''). /*strip existing html tags */
                  split(''), 
        output = '';
    for (var w = 0, l = letters.length; w < l; w++) {
        output += '<span style="color:' + ((w % 2) ? colorpair[0] : colorpair[1]) + ';">' + letters[w] + '</span>';
    }
    el.innerHTML = output;
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xpZqs/

Comment: thank you for listing out these problems! your post is very helpful (as well as every one else's on this question!). I used your code, but I got rid of the form and called the alternate('color1|color2') function from an onload call in the body element and it seems to be working great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this, just replace your JavaScript code with the following (and remove the form from your HTML since you just want this to happen on page load):

```
var HTML = '';

function alternate(colorpair) {
    var el = document.getElementById('alternator');
    if (!HTML) HTML = el.innerHTML;
    var text = HTML.match(/\S\s*(?=\S)/g), output = '';
    for (var w=0; w<text.length; w++) {
        output += '<span style="color:' + ((w%2) ? colorpair[0] : colorpair[1]);
        output += ';">' + text[w] + '</span>';
    }
    console.log(output);
    el.innerHTML = output;
}
alternate(['green', 'purple']);
```

Note that with this method you will also skip spaces so the coloring looks a little better.  Here is what the end result looks like:

[image]

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pzeCQ/

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
var text = HTML.split(' '), output = '';
for (var w=0; w<text.length; w++) {
    output += '<span style="color:' + ((w%2) ? colorpair[0] : colorpair[1]);
    output += ';">' + text[w] + '</span> ';
}
```

With this:

```
for (var c=0; c<HTML.length; c++) {
    output += '<span style="color:' + ((c%2) ? colorpair[0] : colorpair[1]);
    output += ';">' + HTML.CharAt(c) + '</span> ';
}
```

The output's going to be pretty verbose. If you want to skip spaces, you'll need to add a little logic for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a simple demo:

This assumes that the text is already on the page, only affects text (using innerText), and replaces the text inside the div with the required html

```
function alternateColours() {
    var div = document.getElementById("alternator");
    var message = div.innerText;
    html = "";
    var colors = new Array("#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"); // red, green, blue
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
        html += "<span style=\"color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";\">" + message[i] + "    </span>";
    div.innerHTML = html;
}
alternateColours();
```

I would recommend the use of jQuery to attach the function to the page load, much cleaner that having to do it yourself.