# how to make javascript color letters of the alphabet specific colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to use javascript, HTML,CSS to take the English alphabet and color each letter a specific color for a web page or for a javascript dom output.

Any help that anyone could help me with this I really appreciate it.
Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I alternate letter colors on a webpage using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325005/how-do-i-alternate-letter-colors-on-a-webpage-using-javascript)

Comment: @RamaSh that post is way different than what I was looking for. That was using javascript to alternate the colors of a text on a web page not make specific letters specific colors using Javascript.

Comment: same basic idea.... so read the letter in the loop and get a color from it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple example using javascript.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const container2 = document.getElementById("container2");
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'];
const colors = ['#FFAA00', '#DDAA00', '#FFFA00', '#FFAAAA', '#121212', '#F1D3A4', '#FAAA43', '#459878', '#234578', '#ADAEAF', ];
letters.forEach((letter) => {
  const elem = document.createElement('span');
  const r = Math.random() * 255;
  const g = Math.random() * 255;
  const b = Math.random() * 255;
  elem.innerText = letter;
  elem.style.color =  'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')';
  container.appendChild(elem);
});
letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
  const elem = document.createElement('span');
  elem.innerText = letter;
  elem.style.color = colors[index];
  container2.appendChild(elem);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="container2"></div>
```